# I want to take backup of my mysql database using cron in linux server

Tags: php, mysql, linux, cron

I want to take backup of my mysql database using cron in linux server,for that i have written a shell script as follow->
`mysqldump -u root -p***** <Databse_name> > ~/Downloads/abc.sql`
and in **/etc/crontab** i have set a cron like this->
`29 18    * * *   user    /var/www/html/myfun.sh`
It is taking backup but **whole sql database file is not coming**.
I can see a file,named as abc.sql is forming in Downloads with 0 bytes.

Comment: Assuming /var/www/html is a web-accessible directory, you should absolutely move that script to a different location outside the web root. As it is now, it may be possible to download your script from the web, exposing your database root password.

Comment: Where is the 0-byte file appearing?  In `/etc/crontab`, this script would execute as the system root user, but the `~` may or may not correctly expand.  You should use an explicit path `> /home/youruser/Downloads/abc.sql`

Comment: You're leaving a space between -u & the username which shouldn't be there I am guessing it's getting access denied because it doesn't know the username

Comment: Oh wait - to do a dump, you do not use the `mysql` command. Rather `mysqldump -uroot -p**** databasename > /path/to/outputfile.sql`  So the 0-byte file you're seeing is from no stdout output being produced by an incorrect command.

Comment: Have you tried using `mysqldump` directly? `mysqldump -u user -pPASWORD <Database_name> > abc.sql`